# Login failed for user ... SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have installed SQL Server, pragmatically with security mode : SQL that means installation in mixed mode.

And I can login with SQL Server authentication but unfortunately when I want to login with Windows authentication I get the following error :

> Login failed for user

Please help me.

Comment: Have you added your windows user as a user in SQL Server?

Comment: no my instance name is "abc" and my computer name is "def". so am i not be able to connect with def\abc in windows mode ?

Comment: thanx Steve, I added my windows user as a user in SQL and it solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: work out what windows user you are connecting as. You need to be certain - don't make assumptions.

Step 2: Add the windows user to the SQL Server. Here is one guide on how to do it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx

here's a youtube video. Only take note from 02:13:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMATHDoIO8M

The way it works is that firstly the windows user needs to be added as a login to the *SQL Server*.

*Then* that windows login needs to be given access to a database (by ticking access to a database). Do you see your windows user listed if you open up SQL Server, and go to security/logins?

Comment: thanx , I added my windows user to users of SQL and it solved my prob

Answer (score 0):

Buddy do this :- this will solve ua issue

step 1 :- open SQL

step 2 :- Right-click the server, and then click Properties.

step 3 :- On the Security page, under Server authentication, click the SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode option button, and then click OK

step 4 :- In the SQL Server Management Studio dialog box, click OK to restart SQL Server.

It will solve ua issue..

Comment: @Shima.Y its that the issue that u have used single mode or mixed mode, if you havent choose the abv stepsi told this can cause an issue that u r facing.. still doubt on my answer, u can refer official msdn website for this issue, u will get the same steps.

Comment: I installed in mixed mode and now I checked my configuration again to make sure that mixed mode option is checked and it was , so this is not my answer